# terraform - Get private ip of aws launch configuration

Tags: terraform

I have this:

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("script.tpl")}"  
}
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ec21" {
  image_id = "${var.image_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name      = "${var.key_name}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

  user_data =   "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.pgetcd.id}"


  min_size = "${var.min_instances}"
  max_size = "${var.max_instances}"

  vpc_zone_identifier = ["${aws_subnet.sb0.id}", "${aws_subnet.sb1.id}", "${aws_subnet.sb2.id}"]             

 lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

How can i get private IP of aws_launch_configuration.ec21 and send using a variable to template_file of another launch_configuration?

I was try use:

aws_launch_configuration.ec21.ip.private_ip, but this does't work.

Comment: You can't. By design, autoscaling groups will have a changing set of instances associated with them, and as those change, so will their IPs.

Comment: Correction: There are ways you could get the IP addresses, but because they are ephemeral, it will cause issues whenever these instances change. See the note on https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instances.html

Comment: ok, i understand, so i going to need look for another solution. Thakn you @JamieStarke